# SpringMvc+Hibernate: Getting NullPointerException in manually inserting data to table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am getting this error when i am trying to insert manually to MySql table with hibernate. 
I am trying to insert some default data to my application but while inserting manually i am getting Null pointer exception. I am new in java programming so can't able to understand how to fix this error. If anyone can help me with this would me really appreciated..

*User_Role Class :*

```
package com.sanjay31321.sys.model;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity @Table(name="user_role")
public class User_Role {

    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="role_name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

*InsertUserRole*

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.sanjay31321.sys.model.User_Role;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.service.UserRoleService;

public class InsertUserRole {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InsertUserRole.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRoleService userRoleService;

    public void insert() {
        User_Role role = new User_Role();

        role.setId(1);
        role.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        logger.info("id : "+ role.getId() + " | Role : " + role.getName());
        userRoleService.addUserRole(role);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertUserRole.insert(InsertUserRole.java:22)
    com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.DefaultDataInstall.install(DefaultDataInstall.java:23)
    com.sanjay31321.sys.controller.DefaultDataController.postinstall(DefaultDataController.java:31)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

DefaultDataController class

```
package com.sanjay31321.sys.controller;

import java.util.Locale;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.DefaultDataInstall;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.model.Install;

@Controller
public class DefaultDataController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultDataController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/install", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getinstall(Locale locale, Install install) {
        logger.info("Welcome to Install Default Settings page ! GET METHOD : The client locale is {}.", locale);
        return "install";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/install", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postinstall(@Valid  Install install, BindingResult result, Locale locale){
        logger.info("Welcome to Install Default Settings page ! POST METHOD : The client locale is {}.", locale);
        DefaultDataInstall settings = new DefaultDataInstall();
        settings.install();
        return "install";
    }
}
```

DefaultDataInstall class

`package com.sanjay31321.sys.preset;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertCourse;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertFeedback;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertQuestion;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertQuestionSet;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertStudent;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertSubject;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertTeacher;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertUser;
import com.sanjay31321.sys.preset.data.InsertUserRole;

public class DefaultDataInstall {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultDataInstall.class);

    public void install() {

        InsertUserRole role = new InsertUserRole();
        role.insert();
        logger.info("User Role data is installed");
    }
}`

I have attached the classes you asked.

Comment: Show us the code of DefaultDataController.java. How does it get its instance of InsertUserRole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you code on github.

It is showing that error because `userRoleService` in `InsertUserRole` is null. so you can not call any method on it.

**Why?**

You creating `InsertUserRole` object using `new` keyword in `DefaultDataInstall`. `@Autowired` don't work when you do that it only works when `DefaultDataInstall` is also instantiated by spring. Spring can only inject something in an object only if it is creating it.

How to fix it.

Instantiate all the objects inside the `preset` package i.e mark them as `@Component`.

Other way is that You inject ApplicationContext in the controller and pass it to the objects you are creating and get the services from the AppContext.

```
@Controller
public class DefaultDataController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultDataController.class);

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;   

    @RequestMapping(value="/install", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postinstall(@Valid  Install install, BindingResult result, Locale locale){
        logger.info("Welcome to Install Default Settings page ! POST METHOD : The client locale is {}.", locale);       
        DefaultDataInstall settings = new DefaultDataInstall(applicationContext);//create a constructor which acceps ApplicationContext object
        settings.install();
        return "install";
    }

    //other code
}
```

Pass the `ApplicationContext` object to all the order objects where you want to use spring beans.

```
public class DefaultDataInstall {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultDataInstall.class);
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public DefaultDataInstall(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public void install() {

        InsertUserRole role = new InsertUserRole();
        role.setUserRoleService(applicationContext.getBean("userRoleServiceImpl"));
        role.insert();
        logger.info("User Role data is installed");

        //other stuff
    }
}
```

Now you can use the passed service to call methods on them

```
public class InsertUserRole {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InsertUserRole.class);

    private UserRoleService userRoleService;

    public void setUserRoleService(UserRoleService){
        this.userRoleService = userRoleService;
    }

    //other code
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amit. I tried this solution but didn't able to understand it properly so i went with @component. It is working fine now. I would like to thank you to pointing me in right direction.